# Creating select event on text component and creating custom view upon text

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My aim is create custom event on Text Component. When I choose one word or when I highlight couple of words, event should fire to open a "buble view" upon, below or near that specific text.

I have found this package here react-native-selectable-text but it does not provide the functionality that I want.

https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text

Two steps

1) How to create that selectable action. I am not talking about Text prop selectable which only opens a menu of copy, paste, select all options. I want to open a view like that menu. A view which will contain information about highlighted text.

2) How I can render a small box(View comp.) with specific coordinates. Like when I choose that text, box has to be rendered upon or below of the text.

I know direct manipulation. But hard part is how am I going to give that select&highlight action to text component?

Comment: The package that you mentioned, what functionality that you need does it not provide? Is it the specific coordinates of the box part?

Comment: @Jono I am talking about creating a View as a box. Not native menu option on selection of text. There is no way to do this unless I create them native and bridge them to javascript.